# Sorting model instances with Globalize3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, globalize2

The problem seems trivial, but I can't find any reasonable solution. I have list of countries with translations stored in Globalize3 translation tables. How can I fetch the list of countries sorted by name?

Country name isn't stored directly in the model, but in separate table. Is there any reasonable way to sort the result other than manual sql query, or manualy sorting result table after AR query is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Country.with_translations(I18n.locale).order('name')` for current locale.

*Edit*:

You can also use fallbacks:

`Country.with_translations(I18n.fallbacks[I18n.locale]).order('name')`

Comment: Thank you, sorry for late response. :-)

Comment: This comes close, but, with fallbacks, the countries will be sorted arbitrarily; if a translation for the primary language exists, it could still be ordered by its fallback translation :/

Answer (score 3):

```
Country.with_translations.order('name')
```